# Ruby on Rails: remembering state and RESTfulness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I am new to Ruby and Rails.

I made a simple application where the index page diaplays a Cars table with columns for make, model, and type (sportscar, SUV, luxury).

I have made it so I can click a column header and sort by that column

I also added a form above the table with a checkbox for each car type where the user can check/uncheck the boxes and click 'submit' and the table will only show cars with the types that were checked.

What I want to be able to do is sort by some column, and then check some boxes/click submit and show the result with the list still sorted AND also filtered.

Right now, I can either sort or filter, but if I do one action my application forgets about the previous action.

What is the RESTful way to do this?

Should I keep the 'settings' in the session hash, and construct a URI from that every time the user makes a new HTTP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with including sort/filter parameters in the request URI? For example, when you submit the filter form for make of "honda", the uri will be something like `/cars?filter[make]=honda`. If you also include sort options, the uri could be `/cars?filter[make]=honda&sort_by=make`.

Inside your controller, you could access these through the params hash:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @filter = params[:filter]  || {}
    @order  = params[:sort_by] || "created_at"

    @cars = Car.where(@filter).order(@order)
  end
end
```

You can generate these uri's by including the parameters in path helpers in your views:

```
link_to "Only show hondas", cars_path(:sort_by => @order, :filter => {:make => "honda"})
link_to "Sort by year",     cars_path(:sort_by => :year,  :filter => @filter)
```

This way, @filter and @order will be "persisted" between requests unless you explicitly change them. (These links are not DRY... you should generate them dynamically).

Comment: I see the error of my ways now. Thanks for setting us straight.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense as far as not depending on implicit session state.

Answer (score 0):

Any data kept in the session hash is available as long as the user is logged in. It doesn't matter what the current URI is.  You would only need to hack the URI if you wanted to use the `params` hash.

Therefore, you should do something like `session[:sortBy] = :make` whenever the sort action is selected. Then, wherever you currently access `params[:sortBy]` in your controller, pull `session[:sortBy]` instead.

I'm of course making guesses as to what your symbols look like. Allowing us to see some of your own code would help.

Comment: I will get my code uploaded to Github. Am I understanding this correctly: if I make a request to sort after I made a request to filter, the URI should contain the parameters for both the sort and the filter? Thanks for the response.

Comment: No, I wouldn't mess with the URI at all.  Just pull what you need from `session`.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to persist something like that to the session. Sessions should be used lightly, and only for global information that is needed for pretty much every request (current signed in user, things like that). If you start depending on the implicit state of your session, it can bite you in the butt!